# Tidy Census: Removing MOE columns

Tags: r, tidyverse, tidycensus

I am pulling some data through tidycensus from the ACS. When I do this, I get two columns for all the variables I included. Since my final dataset has a lot of variables, is it possible to turn off the pull of the MOE. Failing that, can I delete all columns ending with M, and remove the E at the end of the estimate columns?

```
dv_acs = c(
  var1 = "B25002_001", 
  var2 = "B25002_002", 
  var3 = "C24010_039"
)

acs_vars <- get_acs(
    geography = "tract",
    state = "MD",
    variables = dv_acs ,
    year = 2009,
    output = "wide",
    geometry = FALSE
)
```

Comment: Does this require any API key

Comment: For future folks who find this - tidycensus does require a census API key (its free to register). The user above likely has stored the key to their session but the get_acs function does have a "key" parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how to use tidycensus ... but can answer the second part of your question. You can certainly delete and rename the columns with standard tidyverse functions.

```
library(tidyverse)
df <- tibble(
  column1M = rnorm(10),
  column1E = rnorm(10),
  column2M = rnorm(10),
  column2E = rnorm(10)
)

df %>% select(-ends_with("M")) %>%
  rename_with(~str_remove(.x, "E$"))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can easily handle it with [*tidyselect*](https://tidyselect.r-lib.org/reference/starts_with.html) functions.

```
acs_vars %>% 
  rename_with(.fn = ~ gsub(pattern = "E",
                       replacement = "", 
                       x = .x, 
                       fixed =TRUE), 
              .cols = matches("[0-9]")) %>% 
  select(-ends_with("M"))
```